# select id with the latest date and foreign key

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a table as shown here below.

[image]

I want to select the `id_start_odon` with a particular `id_pasien` and the last date of that particular `id_pasien`. I want to get 15 as the result. I've tried this but it doesn't render what I want.

```
public function get_latest($id_pasien){
    $query = "SELECT s1.id_start_odon FROM start_odon s1 WHERE s1.id_pasien=$id_pasien AND s1.created_at=(SELECT s2* FROM start_odon s2 WHERE s2.id_pasien=$id_pasien AND s2.created_at=MAX(s2.created_at))";
    $res = $this->db->query($query);
    return $query;

}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY`created_at`DESC` gets you the latest date. `limit 1` returns oanly one row. `WHERE id_pasien` `=` `$id_pasien` so it looks for specific `id_pasien`.

```
SELECT `id_start_odon` FROM `start_odon`WHERE `id_pasien` = `$id_pasien` order by `created_at` DESC limit 1
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

This query will work

```
 SELECT id_start_odon FROM start_odon s1 WHERE id_pasien=id_pasien=$id_pasien AND 
 id_start_odon=(select MAX(id_start_odon) from start_odon)
```

since your created_date seems to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
SELECT id_Start_odon FROM t 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(created_at) AS dt FROM t WHERE t.id_pasien = 193
) AS a 
ON a.dt=t.created_at
```

This query will also work if there multiple records withe same date for given id_pasien.

Change **193** with your **$id_pasien**

I hope this will solve your problem,

Comment: @Nadia, could you please accept the answer if you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
 $query = "SELECT id_start_odon FROM start_odon s1 WHERE s1.id_pasien = $id_pasien AND s1.created_at = (SELECT MAX(s2.created_at) FROM start_odon s2 WHERE s2.id_pasien = s1.id_pasien)";
```